# display svg image in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, npm

I want to display a qr-code svg image in a browser with node.js using qr-image npm module. The code:

```
var qr = require('qr-image');
var svg_string = qr.imageSync('I love QR!', { type: 'svg' });
```

and later, in my page.ejs, I have:

```
<%= svg_string %>
```

In the browser I have:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 23 23">
<path d="M1 1h7v7h-7zM11..."/></svg>
```

I just see the text and not the image. I tried with

```
<img <%= svg_string %> >
```

But it's wrong. How can I display my svg image?

Comment: What are you using to bind to `HTML` ? Also `img` requires a `src='xxxx''` and that is when you have an actual image location, if you have a byte array, serialize to `base64` etc. What is `svg_string` ?

Comment: binding to html: view engine used with express: app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); svg_string is the string used to draw the svg image returned by qr-image: svg_string = "<svg xmlns=...</svg>"

Comment: UPDATE: If I write in page.ejs:
    <% qr.image('I love QR!', { type: 'svg' }).pipe(response); %>
then I can see the image but at the top of the html page!
I would like to do something like: 
    qrcode.png = qr.image(...)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this it will be shown in y.

`<%-svg_string %>`